# compare date in cell with today() for conditional formatting

Tags: excel, date

I am trying to create conditional formatting where I compare dates in the cells of a column with today(). However, when I check with evaluate formula, today() gives a short date (`44231`) and my cells are formatted as `24/08/2021`
The result of `=B2<today()` thus results in false even though it is true. How can I solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your "dates" are not actually dates, they are strings that only look like dates.  Sanitize your data.

Comment: Any tips how to do this, the sap that exports this data is pc date structure sensitive and for this to work for my colleagues I need to keep it in dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: Best option is to modify the export to produce actual date data (any opinions on that would require full info on that process).  Second best would be some VBA to scrub the data.  There are lots if posts on SO that deal with this topic

Comment: I managed to solve it. Thanks for pointing out this silly oversight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your string into a date value, which can be done using the `DATEVALUE()` function, explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252). Be very careful working with that function, because it's related to your regional settings: does "01/02/2021" mean the first of February or the second of January?